# Multiple Jssor in one page failing in chrome

Tags: jquery, css, jssor

I did multiple jssor galleries for my portfolio page on

http://www.jmkintela.com/

All sliders are working , except for the last one, the one with the storyboards, it has 600 images and I found that under the google chrome browser, ONLY when it's maximized it's start to cutdown images and not showing them, basically it breaks, but strangely it's only that gallery , and it work perfectly when I resize the window, and also when I cut down the amount of images for less than 100 and on internet explorer.

I think maybe some window resize command that update the size when it's maximized(like.. `$Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);`c  ) could fix this , but my knowledge of jssor and js it's not that deep.
I tried for hours to solve this but it's out of my reach and i'm asking over here.
This is the code I use for the galleries

```
jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

        var jssor_1_SlideoTransitions = [
          [{b:900,d:2000,x:-379,e:{x:7}}],
          [{b:900,d:2000,x:-379,e:{x:7}}],
          [{b:-1,d:1,o:-1,sX:2,sY:2},{b:0,d:900,x:-171,y:-341,o:1,sX:-2,sY:-2,e:{x:3,y:3,sX:3,sY:3}},{b:900,d:1600,x:-283,o:-1,e:{x:16}}]
        ];

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $AutoPlay: 1,
          $SlideDuration: 800,
          $SlideEasing: $Jease$.$OutQuint,
          $CaptionSliderOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorCaptionSlideo$,
            $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideoTransitions
         },
          $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
         },
          $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
         }
       };

        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);
        var jssor_2_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_2", jssor_1_options);
        var jssor_3_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_3", jssor_1_options);
        var jssor_4_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_4", jssor_1_options);
        var jssor_5_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_5", jssor_1_options);
        var jssor_6_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_6", jssor_1_options);
        var jssor_7_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_7", jssor_1_options);
        var jssor_8_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_8", jssor_1_options);
        var jssor_9_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_9", jssor_1_options);
        var jssor_10_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_10", jssor_1_options);
          /*responsive code begin*/
        /*remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing*/
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (refSize) {
                refSize = Math.min(refSize, 1600);
                jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                jssor_2_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                jssor_3_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                jssor_4_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                jssor_5_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                jssor_6_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                jssor_7_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                jssor_8_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);                    
                jssor_9_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                jssor_10_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
           }
            else {
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
           }
       }
        ScaleSlider();
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        /*responsive code end*/
   };
```

and the div structure :

```
  <div id="jssor_1" style="position:relative;margin:0 auto;top:0px;left:0px;width:1024px;height:576px;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;">
        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div data-u="loading" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat 50% 50%;background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);"></div>
        <div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:1024px;height:576px;overflow:hidden;">

          <div>
<img data-u="image" src="http://localhost/img/storyboards/st_001_web.jpg"/>
 </div>

          <div>
<img data-u="image" src="http://localhost/img/storyboards/st_002_web.jpg"/>
 </div>

  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: wow, I guess you have thousands of images.

Comment: Yes, and  the gallery with 600 images is the one with problems..the rest doesn't have more than 100 ...by the way amazing library !

Answer (score 0):

I Fix the problem just temporrarly by adding some if to the js function:

```
   function ScaleSlider() {
        var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
        if (refSize) {
             if (refSize >= 1024) {
                 refSize = Math.max(refSize, 500);
               }
            else {
              refSize = Math.min(refSize, 1024); 
            }

            jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
            jssor_2_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
            jssor_3_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
            jssor_4_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
            jssor_5_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
            jssor_6_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
            jssor_7_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
            jssor_8_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);                    
            jssor_9_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
            jssor_10_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
       }
        else {
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 0);
       }
   }
    ScaleSlider();
    $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
    $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
    $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
    /*responsive code end*/
```

};

I realized that when I max the size of the sliders the problems stop, 
but I actually don't want that behavior in the galleries because beyond 1024 the images start to pixelate, but it's better than broken sliders though...